# How to change update location in Clickonce installer?

Tags: installation, clickonce

I am working on a clickonce installer and want the update location other than the publish location and load it on the server at a different location than the main installer location. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio to publish, go to the "Publish" tab of the project properties, then click the "Updates..." button.  The resulting dialog will allow you to set a different location for updates.

If you are publishing manually, then you'll need to change the deploymentProvider node's codebase value to your update URL in your application file.

Comment: What if the application file is coded signed?  Then you can't change it.